# mp3 won't play on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, fileopener2

I'm getting this error when i'm trying open audio mp3 files on ios:

```
Error status: 9 - Error message: Could not handle UTI
```

I'm using cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.2.1

My code:

```
var local_file = cordova.file.dataDirectory + '1579617669858mp3';
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(local_file, "audio/*", {
        error: function (e) {        
       console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
       if (e.status === 9) {
       AlertInfo("Player must be installed on your device");
             }
             },
           success: function () {
                console.log("success");
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1579617669858.mp3 instead?

Comment: Yes, it was a distraction!